# Daily kill variety. How to tell?

Tags: achievements, guild-wars-2

Is there any way to know what type of monsters have I already slain for the daily kill variety achievment?

I randomly kill mobs untill I have it completed (10 different type of creatures), but some times I'm not sure if I have already killed one type or not.

Does the game offer any clue regarding this?

It would also be nice knowing a creature's type (e.g. beast, human, insect...) in some way. Right now I have to figure that.

Comment: As far as I know, it doesn't tell you which ones you kill, but since it's account based instead character based, you could play a few characters in different starter zones to get the necessary different kills?

Comment: One remark, not on topic, but hopefully helpful. Creatures with white names, those that you can kill with one hit count too. It's an easy way to push your progress forward.

Comment: An easy way to get this achievement is just to be polite, be professional, and kill everything you meet ;)

Comment: @MaciejHehl White name creatures, the one-hit kill mobs, only count towards your daily kill variety *once*. They're all considered one subtype for the purposes of kill variety. So you can't kill a white Sparkfly and a white Rabbit and have it count as 2 different types; they'll only be counted as one.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no way to tell.

You can either keep track manually, or keep killing mobs on your own until it pops.

I've found it helpful to get this achievement over multiple characters; even only two different starting zones should have enough variety to quickly earn the achievement.

Comment: It's interesting knowing at least the fact that you can do this over multiple characters

Comment: @stoldark The achievements page is account-based, not character-based, so you can get progression across all your characters towards the various achievements.

Answer (score 1):

If you open your Achievement window and then open your Slayer Panel you will be able to see all the different Varieties of mobs.