# What are the various enemy types in Guild Wars 2?

Tags: achievements, guild-wars-2

There is a daily achievement called Daily Kill Variety.  I'm curious if there is a list anywhere of what the different enemy types are and what enemies belong to each type.  Today I killed a Ram, a Moose, and a Doe and I only gained 1 toward this achievement (starting from 0 for the day).  Clearly these are all the same type.

Comment: Duplicate of http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/82296/daily-kill-variety-how-to-tell?rq=1

Comment: It's not really the same - the other question wants to know how to keep track, this one wants a list.

Comment: @pleinolijf They're related, but not duplicates.

Comment: check the achievement category for monster kills. 'slayer' i think. I think this will list all of the monster categories.(because you get achievements for slaying x of each type)

Comment: @ColinD: But they don't list all the categories - for example, there is no achievement for slaying Felines, like Stalkers, Jaguar, etc

Comment: @Gwen, good to know. I did not know that list was incomplete.

Answer (score 3):

The [bestiary category](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Category:Bestiary) on the official wiki is a good guideline, each of the subcategories generally count as their own creature type for kill variety.

Comment: This is pretty close, but they list Ram and Moose in separate categories.  Which doesn't align with my results from testing.  Looks like this may be more difficult than I anticipated.

Comment: Ya, it should be used as a loose guideline because it doesn't correspond 100%. It also lists grubs as their own group although, at least for the slayer achievements, they count as wurms.